# String to bold transfomed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actualmente estoy recibiendo data del backend, **un string de numeros** (accountNumber), el cual posee 10 digitos,y es particular de cada usuario. donde el primero es 1, luego 0.. y por ulitmo el accountNumber (puede contener 1 digito o mas)Ej: 1000000032 / 1000002032 / 1000000004. La idea es retornar ese string con los digitos del accountNumber en negrita, Ej. : 10000000**32** / 100000**2032** y asi. Lo que intente hasta ahora :
Usando este como ej: 1000002032

```
const clean = accountNumber.substring(1, 10) ==> '000002032'
const showOnlyAccountNumbers = clean.replace(/^0+/, ''); ==> '2032';
const transformToArray = showOnlyAccountNumbers.split();==> ['2032']
const boldNumbers = showOnlyAccountNumbers.map((each) => {
return <b>{each}</b>
}) ==> {[...]}
```

No estoy consiguiendo el resultado ya que el .map me retorna un array de objeto y no lo que necesito para poder de alguna forma unir eso en un string con el resto.

De antemano , gracias !

Comment: Pero por qué lo haces con un map y no directamente `<b>{showOnlyAccountNumbers}</b>`??? Porque obviamente que map devuelve un array, es un método que se usa para iterar sobre un array...

Comment: Porque necesito luego de alguna forma mostrar el string entero con los numeros en bold mas el resto, no puedo dejarlos por separado ya que el resultado final debe incluir tambien 1000...

Comment: De la BD te viene el accountNumber completo?, o sea asi 1000002032

Comment: si ! Exacto, la pegada es un .get, y manda el string completo. Por lo cual mi idea fue separar los digitos del accountNumber, que son dinamicos,  transformarlos y de alguna forma unirlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es obteniendo el índice del primer elemento distinto de cero. Y aplicamos el tag `bold` a la subcadena que existe a partir de dicho índice.

Si la cadena no tiene ningún número distinto de cero se devuelve la misma cadena.

Para lograrlo, usamos el método [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) y convertimos a número la subcadena resultante, para eliminar los ceros a la izquierdas o no relevantes. Una vez obtenido el valor numérico, lo convertimos en cadena y lo pasamos como argumento del método [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), de esta forma obtenemos el índice en el cual comienza dicha subcadena en la cadena completa.

Por último aplicamos los cambios a partir de dicho índice y devolvemos el resultado.

He creado este ejemplo que puedes adaptar de acuerdo a lo que necesites:

```js
const accountNumbers = [
  '1000000000',
  '1000000032',
  '1000002032',
  '1000000004',
  '1000000320',
];

const boldLastOnes = accountNumbers.map(aNumber => {
  // si solo hay ceros después del primer 1 entonces devolvemos el mismo valor
  if(!parseInt(aNumber.substring(1))) {
    return aNumber;
  }
  const index = aNumber.indexOf(parseInt(aNumber.substring(1)).toString());
  const bold = `<b>${aNumber.substring(index)}</b>`;
  return `${aNumber.substring(0, index)}${bold}`;
});

const addLIValueToUL = (id, value) => {
  const listElement = document.createElement('li');
  listElement.innerHTML = value;
  document.getElementById(id).append(listElement);
}
accountNumbers.forEach(v => addLIValueToUL('not_bold', v));
boldLastOnes.forEach(v => addLIValueToUL('bold', v));
```

```html
Original:
<ul id="not_bold">
</ul>
<br>
Bolded:
<ul id="bold">
</ul>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**Edición**

Usualmente, cuando digo que lo puedes adaptar a tu situación particular la idea es que extraigas la parte esencial de la solución. Sin embargo, dado que al parecer no queda claro como hacerlo, te muestro que se trata simplemente de crear la siguiente función:

```js
function putBoldAccountNumber(aNumber) {
  // si solo hay ceros después del primer 1 entonces devolvemos el mismo valor
  if(!parseInt(aNumber.substring(1))) {
    return aNumber;
  }
  const index = aNumber.indexOf(parseInt(aNumber.substring(1)).toString());
  const bold = `<b>${aNumber.substring(index)}</b>`;
  return `${aNumber.substring(0, index)}${bold}`;
}
```

La cual podrás usar en cualquier cadena que le pases como argumento, por ejemplo:

```js
const accountNumbers = [
  '1000000000',
  '1000000032',
  '1000002032',
  '1000000004',
  '1000000320',
];

function putBoldAccountNumber(aNumber) {
  // si solo hay ceros después del primer 1 entonces devolvemos el mismo valor
  if(!parseInt(aNumber.substring(1))) {
    return aNumber;
  }
  const index = aNumber.indexOf(parseInt(aNumber.substring(1)).toString());
  const bold = `<b>${aNumber.substring(index)}</b>`;
  return `${aNumber.substring(0, index)}${bold}`;
}

accountNumbers.forEach(aNumber => {
  console.log(putBoldAccountNumber(aNumber));
});
```

Comment: Amigo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. El problema esta en que yo recibo la data desde el backend, como un string que respecta a cada usuario en particular. Por lo cual no puedo mapear sobre eso desde el inicio..

Comment: Anda, ya lo tienes hecho, pero para tener éxito en este mundillo, hay que ensuciarse las manos, sino nunca vas a salir adelante. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Bueno ya te dieron la respuesta pero de igual forma quería hacer mi aporte.

La variable que contiene el `accountNumber` la convierto a un arreglo con **spread operator**`[...]` seguido de eso lo itero y con `findIndex` busca la mitad que divide a los números que son desiguales de **1 y 0**, ahora ya teniendo la esa división puedo dividir el array en 2 con el metodo `slice()`

**Resultado**

> 1 inicio = números iguales a 1 y 0 ejm: 100000
>
> 2 final = números desiguales de 1 y 0 emj: 2032

Al final los concateno con templete literals y el array **final** lo pongo en negrita.

```
let Bold = document.getElementById("accountNumber")

let accountNumber = "1000002032"
const newArray = [...accountNumber]

let mitad = newArray.findIndex(element => {
    return element !== "1" && element !== "0"
})

const inicio =  newArray.slice(0, mitad).join("");
const final = newArray.slice(mitad).join("");

Bold.innerHTML = `${inicio}<b>${final}</b>`
```

HTML

```
<ul id="accountNumber"></ul>
```

**RESULTADO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Tengo que agregar que lo hice recibiendo un solo elemento que podría ser de un array o un objeto y no como @Mauricio Contreras que lo hizo con un array desde el inicio